# Returning a view to an ajax call and replacing html page throws 'appendchild' exception in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an ajax call like this below where I'm returning a view like this

```
return View("Finish");
```

This has the entire html page as a string as the response, so I want to replace the page with it, but when I do I receive an error

> Unhandled exception at line 82, column 3 in https://localhost:44368/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js
>   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference occurred

Funny thing is it does set the html so I see the correct page on screen, I just see the exception in JQuery as well!

```
var options = {
  url: scope.enumControllers.saveEvent,
  type: "post",
  data: viewModel
};

$.ajax(options)
  .done(function(response) {
    if (response.error === true) {

      yb.base.eventAlert(response.message, "error");
    } else {

      $("html").html(response); // error here trying to set the page to the response html string

    }
  })
  .always(function() {

  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    yb.base.eventAlert("Error saving data. Please contact the help desk.", "error");
  });
```

Comment: It is not good idea to replace entire page via ajax. Note that you also replaces all scripts on the page and if your response contains some scripts, it couldnt be loaded..

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to return the entire view then why using ajax?